# Django GenericViewSet: Can't create custom routes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling to understand how class-based generic views work in Django. The documentation doesn't cover generic views in detail. 
I've created a custom `@list_route` but there seems to be no way of calling it. Here's the code:

view:

```
class AnalyticsViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = models.BookingAnalytics.objects.exclude(status=booking_constants.BookingState.deleted)
    permission_classes = [DRYPermissions, ]
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, ]
    filter_class = filters.AnalyticsFilter
    serializer_class = serializers.AnalyticsDetailSerializer
    serializer_classes = {}

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_role_admin:
            raise exc.PermissionDenied()

        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        filtered_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

        data = {
            'stats': {
                ....
            }
        }

        return response.Ok(data)

    @list_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='export')
    def export(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        filtered_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

        recipients = []

        if 'recipients' in request.data:
            recipients = request.data['recipients']

        ....

        return response.NoContent()
```

model:

```
class BookingAnalytics(UUIDModel, TimeStampedModel):
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('booking analytic')
        verbose_name_plural = _('booking analytics')
        ordering = ('-booking_date', '-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid

    @staticmethod
    @authenticated_users
    def has_read_permission(request) -> bool:
        return request.user.is_role_admin or request.user.is_role_client

    @staticmethod
    @authenticated_users
    def has_write_permission(request) -> bool:
        return request.user.is_role_admin or request.user.is_role_client

    @staticmethod
    @authenticated_users
    def has_object_list_permission(request) -> bool:
        return request.user.is_role_admin

    @authenticated_users
    def has_object_export_permission(self, request) -> bool:
        return request.user.is_role_admin
```

Here, the default `list` route works just fine. However, the `export` route isn't called at all.

What is it that I'm missing?
[image]

[image]

Contrary to that, I have another viewset with many custom routes, and they work perfectly:

```
class BookingViewSet(
    MultipleSerializerMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    queryset = models.Booking.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [DRYPermissions, ]
    filter_backends = [filters.BookingFilterBackend, filters.BookingExportFilterBackend, DjangoFilterBackend, ]
    filter_class = filters.BookingFilter
    pagination_class = BookingViewSetPagination
    serializer_class = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer

    serializer_classes = {...}

    ....

    @list_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='export-bookings')
    def export_bookings(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        filtered_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)

        recipients = []

        if 'recipients' in request.data:
            recipients = request.data['recipients']

        ....

        return response.NoContent()
```

Comment: I cannot see `Request Method: GET` in you API call

Comment: the `export` api call is a POST request.

Comment: okay, but I cannot see any `Request Method` in your screen shot @saran3h. Just try with Postman.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera I've attached one from swagger.

Comment: the interesting part would be the server's response in the browser console. Swagger seems to think your dev server doesn't run so you should make sure it didn't crash

Comment: oh wait. What's that return `response.NoContent()` ? definitively not DRF.

Comment: @saran3h, check whether your server is running by using `netstat` command. If it is running the `State` should be `ESTABLISHED`.

Comment: That's deliberate. I perform some async task so I don't have a response. The problem is that the control doesn't even enter the method.
And yes the server is up. the application is running and fetching data from all the end points. `netstat` shows ESTABLISHED as well.

Comment: yes @saran3h, I also think how `Request Method` is not available in your request headers.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera
After a bit of research, I figured that this is a `preflight` request which first checks whether the server is up by sending an `OPTIONS` request first. The issue is most probably because of `CORS` headers not being set while calling the api I wonder why :|

Comment: @saran3h instead of that I think your `AnalyticsViewSet` class doesn't support `POST` request,   try to modify with `class AnalyticsViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):`. I hope it's work. every [Concrete View Classes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes) should have one or more Mixin.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera still the same. Custom routes using `@list_route or @detail_route` are not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194522/discussion-between-kushan-gunasekera-and-saran3h).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I end up making it work.

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def export(request, format=None):
    qs = models.BookingAnalytics.objects.all()

    filtered_queryset = filters.AnalyticsFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)

    recipients = []

    if 'recipients' in request.data:
        recipients = request.data['recipients']
    ....

    return response.NoContent()
```

urls.py

```
...
    url(r'^export$', export, name='export'),
...
```